# Semantic-UI-React, selection, multi, can't set defaultValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have React component:

```
<Dropdown
    placeholder={field[propName].label}
    id={propName}
    fluid
    multiple
    selection
    search
    defaultValue={defaultOptions}
    options={options}
/>
```

So `options` and `defaultOptions` is the same structure arrays `{text: 'string, value: 'string'}`.

In semantic UI source code I found this:

```
/** Initial value or value array if multiple. */
    defaultValue: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.string,
      PropTypes.number,
      PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.number,
      ])),
    ])
```

That the reason why my code above gives me error:

```
`Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `defaultValue` supplied to `Dropdown`. Check the render method of `View`.`
```

So question is how then I should set defaultValue for multi selection type of Dropdown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

defaultValue cannot be an object for semantic-UI-react. It can only be a value. http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown. If you look at the props of defaultValue, the docs say that it can be a string, number, or arrayOf.

I usually set mine to value of the dropdown - using immutabilityJS - when it is switched onChange.

```
<Dropdown
    placeholder={field[propName].label}
    id={propName}
    fluid
    multiple
    selection
    search
    defaultValue={dropdownList.get('forWhat')}
    options={options}
    onChange={(e, {value}) => this.updateDropdownList('forWhat',[value:value, text:"works"])}
/>
```

Comment: I'm trying to pass array of string with value, same value I use in {text: '', value: ''}, object, and it still doesn't work

Comment: I just tried my code with [value:value, text:'works'] and that does work. Can you post more of your code. Maybe it is something else

Comment: *[{value:value, text:'works}] - forgot to add the {}

Comment: that array as options right? so lets assume we have 3 object in that array, value is JSON.stringified object. So what would you set as defaultValue? Just array of values?

Comment: oh wait, I'm now getting that same error. It appears that you can't do an array of objects or JSON.stringified object in semantic-ui-react. Sorry for the confusion. You can however do [value, "string", 100]. But objects are invalid. If you'd like to see that feature, post it on https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues as an issue

Comment: That's not good, why can I use string but can't JSON. stringified  object) But thanks!