# Semantic UI React Form Select - set selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, dropdown, semantic-ui

In Semantic UI React, I can't figure out how to set the selected value of a dropdown (on an edit form, for example). Here's how the options come in:

```
const options = users.map(user => ({
  key: user.id,
  text: user.name,
  value: user,
}))
```

And the form looks like this. I've tried setting the `defaultValue`, `value`, etc, but nothing has worked for me yet.

```
<Form.Field>
  <Form.Select
    fluid
    selection
    label="Users"
    name="users"
    options={options}
    defaultValue={user}
    onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
  />
</Form.Field>
```

I would assume the `defaultValue` needs to be something like:

```
{ key: 1, text: 'Tania', value: tania }
```

But according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473002/semantic-ui-react-selection-multi-cant-set-defaultvalue), the default value of a [Dropdown](http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/) (which is apparently the underlying code of [Select](http://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/select/) "sugar") can't be an object.

Comment: actually `value` is also described as "{bool|string|number|arrayOf}". Is not it better to change code so `value` for each option would be `user.id`?

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution was to do something like this:

```
const options = users.map(user => {
  if (user.name === selectedUser.name) {
    return {
      key: user.id,
      text: user.name,
      value: user,
      active: true,
      selected: true,
    }
  }
  return {
    key: user.id,
    text: user.name,
    value: user,
  }
})
```

I also set `text={user.name}` to the `Select` component and it works well enough now, though the first option still appears selected-but-not-active.